# set in useState does not reload the data on the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just started learning how to work with React and I ran into a problem that I still can't seem to solve.

I'm trying to program a simple app for adding tasks like a simple to-do list.

But when I want to add a task and save the data via `useState`, the new data is not written to the page.

i have code in file AllTasks.js:

```js
     const [myTasks, setMyTasks] = useState(data);

    const tasksHandler = (id) => {
        const filteredTasks = myTasks.filter((oneTask) =>{
           return oneTask.id !== id;
        })
        setMyTasks(filteredTasks);
    }

    const checkID = () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < myTasks.length; i++){
            if(i === myTasks.length -1){
                return myTasks[i].id + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    const addNewTask = (newTask) => {
        let task = {
            id: checkID(),
            name: newTask
        };
        const newTasks = myTasks;
        newTasks.push(task);
        setMyTasks(newTasks);
    }

    const deleteAllTasks = () => {
        setMyTasks([]);
    }

    return(
        <div className='tasks'>
            <Title />
            <AddTasks addTask={addNewTask}/>
            {
                myTasks.map((oneTask) => {
                    const {id, name} = oneTask;

                    return <div className='one-task' key={id}>
                        <p>{name}</p>
                        <button onClick={() => tasksHandler(id)}><img src={deleteImg} alt='todoApp'/></button>
                    </div>
                })
            }
            <button className='main-button' onClick={deleteAllTasks}>Delete all tasks</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AllTasks;
```

The code in the AddTask.js file that I use to send the new task to the AllTasks.js file

```js
import './AddTask.css';
import addImg from "../img/plus.png";

const AddTask = (props) => {

    const add = () => {
        const input = document.getElementById('new-task');
        const newTask = input.value;
        if(input.value.length > 0){
            props.addTask(newTask);
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className='add-task'>
            <input type='text' id='new-task'></input>
            <button id='send-task' onClick={add}><img src={addImg} alt='todoApp'/></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddTask;
```

I don't understand why when I click on add task and run the `addNewTask()` function, why doesn't the added task appear on the page? When I upload new data to myTasks via `setMyTasks(newTaskt)`?

Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: Everyone hates reading docs but I suggest you read through the docs once. Particularly the beta reactjs docs. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Comment: @Binit There should be a bot that scans react questions and automatically closes them. I see at least 5 questions like that per hour

Comment: Your `checkID` function may create the same IDs over time, which doesn't break anything in this code, but still you can do better. Here an imo. better code: `const newId = useMemo((current = 0) => () => \`id${++current}\`, []);`

Answer (score 1):

Try change final line of addNewTask function from `setMyTasks(newTasks);` to  `setMyTasks([...newTasks]);`

Comment: This still mutates the old state, but then makes a copy of that mutated array so that `setMyTasks` recognizes it as "new" value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are adding new data inside existing array, react needs a brand new array to update it's state and keep track of state.

In `addNewTask` function instead of adding element to the existing array you should do

```js
setState((previousStateOfArray) => {
return [...previousStateOfArray, newElement];
})
```

Or shorthand would be `setState(prev => [...prev, newElement])`

Answer (score 0):

Should use immutable state setting:

```
setMyTasks([...newTasks]);
```

Comment: This still mutates the old state, but then makes a copy of that mutated array so that `setMyTasks` recognizes it as "new" value.